# CCParticleSystemQuad works as intended every second time

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, particles

I'm using CCParticleSystemQuad for particles, loading it from plist:

```
flourEmitter = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"FlourParticles.plist"];
```

But it works not every time. Every second or third time I start a game, particles look different from what I've set them up and there are errors saying it couldn't load image.

> ```
> cocos2d: CCTexture2D. Can't create Texture. cgImage is nil
> cocos2d: Couldn't create texture for file: in CCTextureCache
> ```

Of course the image is there and the next time i launch game it works as intended.

I cannot think of any ways how to debug this error.

Comment: device or simulator? Particle effects in Simulator may not render precisely as on a device.

Comment: ipad 3. What is interesting, I have very similar particles class with different plist and image and it works without problems. I cant find any differences between them that could have caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made my filenames lowercase and problem disappeared. It looks like little tricks from '90-ties still work.